# Parity Vault password lost

Tags: parity, password

Is there anyway to contact EthCore to have the password on my Vault reset?  I could certainly be wrong here, but I dont think the Vault of part of the decentralized network or encrypted to any large degree.  Within my vault is my parity wallet which contains my ETH.  My apple icloud password was inadvertenly overwritten with the wrong password and Apple has no way to access a list of previous passwords.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. A _vault_ is not a wallet.

Answer (score 1):

All you lost is your *metadata*. Vaults are a privacy feature, not a security feature.

You can manually import your JSON keys by going to the Accounts tab, click on "new Account", select from "JSON File", and find the Vault's directory on your disk (a subdirectory in your keys directory named after the vault).

After import you can use the account like you always used to do.